# Assetic route gives 404 for javascript

Tags: symfony, assetic

Just following the cookbook for Symfony2 2.3 and trying to use [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) for assets management.

I'm here: [How To Use Assetic for Asset Management](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-including-javascript), using a fresh 'install' of Symfony2 2.3.3 with vendors.

So I generated a skeleton with `php app/console generate:bundle` and it loads as it should.

I then created two new folders under `Resources`, `public` and `js` and just created a my.js with a console.log() in it.

Now when I reload the page I just get
`[18:53:23.126] GET app_dev.php/js/b36694f_part_1_myjs_1.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]`

And if I do `php app/console route:debug` it's created as I would expect:

```
Name                      Method Scheme Host Path
_assetic_b36694f          ANY    ANY    ANY  /js/b36694f.js
_assetic_b36694f_0        ANY    ANY    ANY  /js/b36694f_part_1_myjs_1.js
```

It looked to me like this was some magic that would just work, and that dumping the assets comes later when I want to run it in prod. Iv'e seen some posts about running with `--watch` but that should only be necessary when running with `use_controller: false` ?

Any tips, pointers or anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it..
It was in the Nginx-config:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

I commented this out and, lo and behold, did it spring to life.

I guess that's what you get for copying configs from another project.

Thank you SO!